# Connect SQL Server Management Studio 2014 with directadmin database

Tags: sql-server, directadmin

I've been trying to connect SSMS 2014 with my database for quite a while now but it's still not working.

I hosted my website on versio.nl that uses directadmin. I've added my IP to the access hosts of my database. I forwarded port 3306 on my router and disabled my firewall. I use the correct data to connect to the database but everytime I try to do it I get the message:

> Cannot connect to XXX.XX.XXX.XXX
>
> Named Pipes Provider, error: 40

and a MySQL Server error 53

Is there anything I missed here? Maybe in the directadmin console?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding port no 3306 default used for MySQL And SQL Server has default port 1433 So please check it again:

To Resolve this you can follow below steps:

1. SQL services should be started
2. Enable Named Pipes SQL Configuration Manager ==> SQL Server Network Configuration ==> Protocols ==> Named Pipes ==> Right-click ==> Restart
3. Check "SQL Server Authentication" or "Windows Authentication mode" Optoins
4. Use correct Server Name.

More step by step i founded [here](http://www.technologycrowds.com/2014/02/could-not-open-connection-to-sql-server.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your steps but it didn't work. Gonna try some other stuff and will let you know if I find the solution :)